# Prefilled realm object server database

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to keep initial version(prefilled) of realm database to Realm Object Server which will be synchorized once user authorized first time?

Then users will be able to read/modify their copies. It is not multiediting - every user has it's own database, just prefilled from a server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can setup a Realm function that monitors either when the user is created or when they access the Realm for the first time, and then let the server fill the Realm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another detail: 
1. Is this available in developer (free) version of realm? I browsed through docs on realm.io and didn't find anything like this, where to find documentation?
2. I am developing language learning app that allows user to pick which language to learn. Every language has its own database (different file path) - the same structure, but different data. Would it work in this case? 
3. Is it possible to peform migrations in this case? (different versions of db)

Comment: 4. I don't see an option to create function for all users - field is required to be filled. What to do?